# Cant execute delete query properly using rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to deleting some rows of table `info` comparing another table `type`,
my code goes as below. I am not getting any error or exception still I am unable to delete the data. Please suggest me

```
 String query = "delete from info where _id in " + 
                   "( select  a._id " +
                    " from info  a, type b," +
                    " where  a.t_id = b._id and b.type_name = 'Petrol'  )";

try{
     database.rawQuery(query,null);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the SELECT part to see what it returns ?

Comment: it returns ID's , 
I checked executing whole query using Sqlite, there its working properly. I am able to delete in SQLITE

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `select  a._id " +
                    " from info  a, type b," +
                    " where  a.t_id = b._id and b.type_name = 'Petrol'``?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` is meant for **querying** --> SELECT statement.

To **modify** your data with raw SQL, you need to use [`SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
database.rawQuery(query,null).moveToFirst();
```

instead of

```
database.rawQuery(query,null);
```